# Can't install geopandas in pycharm virtual enviroment

Tags: python, pycharm, geopandas, virtual-environment

I am trying to install geopandas in a virtual enviroment in pycharm . But there is this error message :

```
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached geopandas-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (928 kB)
Collecting fiona
  Using cached Fiona-1.8.13.post1.tar.gz (1.2 MB)

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'G:\Practice Prcatice Practice\pydatatest\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\fiona\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried all the solutions I could find on internet like doing this :

```
pip install wheels
pip install pipwin

pipwin install numpy
pipwin install pandas
pipwin install shapely
pipwin install gdal
pipwin install fiona
pipwin install pyproj
pipwin install six
pipwin install rtree
pipwin install geopandas
```

But nothing seems to work for me . Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you looked at the log?

Comment: the event log has the same message